# Pegar alguns elementos de uma variavel JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho uma variavel em JavaScript que guarda um JSON, similar a esse:

```
{
    "estado":
    [
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SP",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SC",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de RJ",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        }
    ]
}
```

Só que a com muito mais elementos. Como faço para recuperar elementos de 1 a 5, 6 a 10, 11 a 15 e assim por diante?

Comment: Você quer obter por intervalo os objetos dentro de estado ou irá ter vários estados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para buscar por range, você pode utilizar o [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para fazer essa filtragem no seu array, exemplo:

```
var yourJson = {
    "estado":
    [
        {
        ...
        }
    ]
}

result = yourJson.estado.splice(/*inicial*/ 1, /*final*/ 5);

console.log(result);
```

Lembre de fazer o [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) do seu Json para a variavel :)

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fLxxu99t/)